# Hacer [access] sinónimo de [ms-access]

Tags: soporte, estado-completado, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

SOes cuenta con

- [access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access)
- [ms-access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access)
- [ms-access-2010](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access-2010)

Propongo que [access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) se haga sinónimo de [ms-access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) y que se deje [ms-access-2010](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access-2010) para preguntas específicas a esa versión.

Comment: Solo para referencia, en el sitio en inglés, la etiqueta [`access`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) se usa para otra cosa, aunque siempre surge confusión allí también con *Microsoft Access*. En lo personal, estoy de acuerdo con tu propuesta.

Comment: Gracias. Las preguntas mas recientes en SO con la etiqueta 'access'  deberían usar la 'ms-access' :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hecho. Se ha creado el sinónimo:

> [ms-access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) (etiqueta maestra) - [access](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access)

Como dice @sstan, en inglés puede variar el significado, ya que significa *acceso*, pero en español, **access**, solo es para las de ***M****icro****S****oft*.